# When doing feature selection, are features like "year", "month" considered as ordinal features or should I convert them to strings?

Tags: dataset, feature-selection, categorical-data, encoding

I am working on a hotel reservation dataset that has both categorical and numerical (continuous and discrete) features (26 columns, 30244 rows). Target is also categorical and it says if the user "Checked in", "Cancelled" or "No-Show".

In the dataset, I have some features such as Income range (<25K, 25K -- 50K, >50K), check-in year (2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), check-out year, check-in month (1,2,3,..,12) and check-out month. I want to do feature selection on my dataset.

I considered income range as an ordinal feature and mapped it as (<25K: 0, 25K -- 50K: 1, >50K: 2)

I am a little confused about what I should do with above mentioned other features. Should I consider them as ordinal features and map them as I have done with income range? Or, should I convert them into strings and perform a categorical feature selection technique on them?

Comment: the question is not clear - are you asking about how to encode dates ? please edit and make sure the question is crisp and clear - don't afraid of using bullet points !